# Pydantic Reponse Model for List of dictionary and Integer

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

I am migrating to Fastapi from Flask and want to create a pydantic Reponse Model. Below is the response.

```
[
[
    {
        "prob": 0.504382973684,
        "server": "sdkjfhkjsdjh1223"
    },
    {
        "prob": 0.378097465773,
        "server": "sdfjkhkjsdj8233y3"
    },
    {
        "prob": 0.370512958735,
        "server": "sdkfjhkjh239486989884"
    },
    {
        "prob": 0.369599161425,
        "server": "sdkjfhkj238683"
    },
    {
        "prob": 0.369443692878,
        "server": "sdjhjdfh3764"
    }
],
200
]
```

I created below response class

```
class predictionResponse(BaseModel):
    """
    Response Model for Prediction
    """
    tuple: [list, int]
```

But it failing the validation

```
  File "pydantic/main.py", line 197, in pydantic.main.ModelMetaclass.__new__
  File "pydantic/fields.py", line 506, in pydantic.fields.ModelField.infer
  File "pydantic/fields.py", line 436, in pydantic.fields.ModelField.__init__
  File "pydantic/fields.py", line 557, in pydantic.fields.ModelField.prepare
  File "pydantic/fields.py", line 831, in pydantic.fields.ModelField.populate_validators
  File "pydantic/validators.py", line 760, in find_validators
RuntimeError: error checking inheritance of [<class 'list'>, <class 'int'>] (type: list)
```

Can anyone suggest how to fix it.

Comment: What's the context in which you're instantiating the model? FastApi? Bit confused by typing... normally a response might be `dict`, and BaseModel uses dict keys for class attributes. Here your class contains attribute called `"tuple"`, (which should get a different name because `tuple` is a keyword in python), and then the response example you give is a `list`, not a `tuple`.

Comment: I tried    prediction: tuple[list, int]
TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
But it is giving error as well

Comment: What Python version are you using?

Comment: i am using python 3.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [custom root type](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/models/#custom-root-types) like this:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel


class Item(BaseModel):
    prob: float
    server: str


class Response(BaseModel):
    __root__: tuple[list[Item], int]


TEST_DATA = '''
[
    [
        {
            "prob": 0.1,
            "server": "foo"
        },
        {
            "prob": 3.14,
            "server": "bar"
        }
    ],
    200
]
'''

instance = Response.parse_raw(TEST_DATA)
print(instance.json(indent=4))
```

Output:

```json
[
    [
        {
            "prob": 0.1,
            "server": "foo"
        },
        {
            "prob": 3.14,
            "server": "bar"
        }
    ],
    200
]
```

---

If you are on Python `<3.9`, obviously use [`typing.List`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.List)/[`typing.Tuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Tuple) instead of the built-in `list`/`tuple` generic aliases:

```py
from typing import List, Tuple

from pydantic import BaseModel


class Item(BaseModel):
    prob: float
    server: str


class Response(BaseModel):
    __root__: Tuple[List[Item], int]
```

Comment: Actually if I see the output its not tuple. I am trying something like List[List[Dict[Item]], int] but its not working. Can you please help.

Comment: What output? The one I showed in my amswer is **JSON**. It only has arrays anyway. Both `list` and `tuple` in Python are turned into arrays in JSON. I am assuming you are interested in that because you tagged this question with FastAPI. Besides, `list` is parameterized with only one type and it is homogeneous in its type parameter. You cannot say _"first item of Type `T` and second item of type `U`"_. But you _can_ do that with `tuple`.